# AVD does not start, gives IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When running my app on the AVD, I get these errors on startup:

```
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.wampec.activeparty; is package not installed?
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.wampec.activeparty; is package not installed?
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:369)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
03-26 06:25:29.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1969):     ... 11 more
```

Why are these occurring, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing a few things:

- Manually uninstall the App from your device/emulator
- Scrap your AVD and create a new one
- Clean your project
- Remove project from your workspace and import it again
- Last resort: Uninstall your IDE (eclipse, netbeans etc..) and install it again.

For me, usually one of those works. Best of luck!